# Как убрать подсказки в Preview Android STudio

Tags: android

Кто знает, как убрать эти подсказки из Preview? Раньше их небыло. Щяс из - за эитх подсказек, у меня процессор гудеть начинает и работает на 90%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше уж скринами. Видео на левый сайт не все готовы идти смотреть. Ну или на youtube его можно выложить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб,а как добавить сюда его? 21 век, видео добваить на форум нельзя)))

Comment: Видео никого не интересует, скриншотов достаточно.

Comment: @Andro, да хотя бы и просто ссылкой. Но лучше, конечно, скрины + описание словами.

Comment: @Andro, _21 век, видео добваить на форум нельзя)))_ - но gif-ку то можно ;)

Comment: @Andro, по сути вопроса - может можно просто эту панельку закрыть? Тогда и лагать, может, перестанет. Вряд ли её можно настроить не правя исходники студии)

Comment: @woesss, блин вообще забыл про них)